# pip install dependencies in custom directory

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install couple of modules via `pip` into custom directory using flag `--target`.

e.g.:

`pip3 install --target /custom/module/location /path/to/package1`

Everything works just fine. By adding `/custom/module/location` to `PYTHONPATH` I can use my `package1`.

But when I try to install `package2` which requires `package1` (located in `/custom/module/location`) pip throws:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ...
No matching distribution found ...
```

Basically:

```sh
PYTHONPATH=/custom/module/location
pip3 install --target /custom/module/location /path/to/package1
pip3 install --target /custom/module/location /path/to/package2
```

does not work, but

```sh
pip3 install --user /path/to/package1
pip3 install --user /path/to/package2
```

works just fine. Is there any way of telling pip to look into custom location `/custom/module/location` other than `PYTHONPATH`?

btw when using first method, `pip3 list` can see the `package1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by using raw setuptools.
First add a path to `PYTHONPATH` and then install local packages.

```sh
EXTRAPATH=/home/path/of/directory/lib/python3.5/site-packages
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$EXTRAPATH
cd /path/to/package1 && python setup.py --prefix=/home/path/of/directory
cd /path/to/package2 && python setup.py --prefix=/home/path/of/directory
```

Answer (score 4):

I think [target](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-t) switch will be used like this:

```
pip install --target=/home/path/of/directory package_name
```

You need to add `/home/path/of/directory` to `PYTHONPATH` to actually use them from that location.

You can upgrade pip by:-

```
pip install -U pip
```

Comment: I'm installing local packages, which is why pip install argument is poiting to a directory containing `setup.py`

Comment: no virtualenv on the server nor root access, thats why I'm installing modules to custom folder. [setup.py](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html) installation is working just fine without virtualenv (for example `package1` and other pakcages are working fine)